# Graduate Admission Application

Tags: masters

What does this question mean in an application for MS: 
"Do you have partial funding for your graduate education? "
or
"Do you have full funding for your graduate education? "

Comment: This can mean different things in different places, say the US and Europe, for example. Where are you asking about?

Comment: It's for MS in US

Answer (score 1):

It means are the fees going to be paid fully or partially.

They want to know they are going to get the money.

It may also be partially-funded is covering tuition only for example.